# Why does Nusach Ashkenaz say Ledovid after Maariv?

Tags: tefilla, nuschaot, nusach-ashkenaz, elul, nusach-sefard

According to my understanding, Nusach Sefard says Ledovid Hashem Ori after Shacharis and Mincha while Nusach Ashkenaz seems to say it after Shacharis and Maariv. Why this difference?

[I wrote the title from my perspective, but it applies equally the other way]

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is one of the times that nusach sfard is correct in keeping the original minhag. The Ramma 581 siff one says to blow shofar in the erev. The Mishna Berurah when tagging on the minhag to say lidovid mentions that erev is after mincha. The Chayei Adam and Aruch Hashulchan say the same. The Igros Moshe in O'ch part 4 siman 21 ois 5 explains the minhag of blowing shofar in the evening had to have been during the day because we can't blow shofar from the beginning of the night untill chatzos due to it being a time of din. He explains that erev means after mincha and brings a proof for this. Or he says it was actually after Maariv but only if they davened mib'od yom, while it was still daytime. He goes on to explain why we only blow once in the morning.

I will add that being that the shofar blowing and saying lidovid are put together in this sugya, than its possible the ashkenazi minhag started when everyone was davening maariv before nightfall and continued even when people started davening after nightfall.

Answer (score -1):

Neither. Nusach Ashkenaz never took on the minhag of adding LeDovid Hashem Ori after Shacharis or Ma'ariv. Instead, it was Nusach Polin and Lita.

Comment: Using the term "Nusach Ashkenaz" in a manner different from how the OP did isn't helpful to anyone. (You are of course correct that many communities did not adopt this late and controversial addition to the prayer service, and more people would remember that if Artscroll wasn't seen as the official representation of the one Jewish tradition. But I digress...)

Comment: You can't fault my accuracy

Comment: https://xkcd.com/169/ The fact is you aren't more accurate than the OP. You are just using different conventions.