# Recitation of Psalm 27 between Elul and Shmini Atzeret

Tags: tefilla, tehilim-psalms, elul

[Psalm 27](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.27?lang=bi) (*leDavid Hashem ori*) is said between Elul and Shmini Atzeret at *shacharit* and *mincha* in *nusach sfard* and at *shacharit* and *arvit* in *nusach ashkenaz*.

What is the origin of this practice and what is its intent?

Comment: On the difference in placement between nusachim see [Why does Nusach Ashkenaz say Ledovid after Maariv?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/46145/11501)

Comment: Only some modern variants of Nusach Ashkenaz and Sefard say it. Just about no one said it until 150 years ago

Comment: @DoubleAA thanks, yes I saw some of your other comments indicating such. I didn't find the duplicate though despite searching for a while. Got stuck on Psalm vs. Tehilim I guess. Thanks

Comment: It's about as much a part of Nusach Ashkenaz as Parshat HaMan or the Akeda is. Printed in most Siddurim, but in no way obligatory or original. Some people with kabbalistic practices say them.

Answer (score 0):

chabad.org quotes a number of reasons [here](https://www.chabad.org/holidays/JewishNewYear/template_cdo/aid/3440228/jewish/Why-Say-LDovid-Hashem-Ori-Psalm-27-During-the-Month-of-Elul.htm) - I'd love to see more explanations

> The Midrash tells us that “my light” (אוֹרִי) is associated with Rosh
>   Hashanah and “my salvation” (וְיִשְׁעִי) is associated with Yom
>   Kippur. We also find that a later verse in the Psalm, “That He will
>   hide me in His tabernacle . . .” (כִּי יִצְפְּנֵנִי בְּסֻכּוֹ), is
>   associated with Sukkot. [...]
>
> The earliest mention of the custom seems to be the work Sefer Shem Tov
>   Katan, by the Kabbalist Rabbi Binyamin Benish Cohen, published in
>   1706. **He writes that one who recites this psalm in a state of holiness, purity and great concentration will have his prayers
>   answered and that it has the power to nullify Divine decrees.** [...]
>
> Another explanation is that **this is a time of Divine mercy, as it
>   was when Moses achieved forgiveness for the people after the sin of
>   the Golden Calf. Every year, it is the time when G‑d is especially
>   accessible**, like a king who goes out to the field to make Himself
>   available to any subjects who wish to greet him.